# COUNTIF & CONDITIONAL FORMATTING WHEN USING NOT EQUAL TO ("<>")

Tags: microsoft-excel

When values are input onto a cell on "LOGIN" column, corresponding cell on "BADGE" column using VLOOKUP either returns "0" or any other value other than 0.

Encountering issues with "COUNTIF" and "CONDITIONAL FORMATTING" when "LOGIN" column is blank to begin with.

1. With conditional formatting on Badge Column, When value is "0" it turns Blue, otherwise Yellow. It is all yellow on first image as all cells are "<>0" to begin with since they are blank. Is there a way of going around this such that if cells on "login" column are blank then corresponding cells on badge columns are blank too as shown on selected cells on second image which I have manipulated by clearing formatting?
2. Again with COUNTIF, understandably adding up values when "login" column is blank returns the total number of cells on the range whit this formula >>>> =COUNTIF(I3:I32:"<>0") . I would like this to be zero from the start until values are added onto LOGIN column.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Comment: Why don't you try this,,, `AND(ISBLANK($A1),ISBLANK($B1))`

Comment: >>When value is "0" it turns Blue.<< Which value?

Comment: @Lee using vlookup on column “login” , it will either pull up “0” or any other value other than 0 on corresponding cells on Badge column

Comment: For your COUNTIF problem, could you count the zeroes instead of the not zeroes, and subtract this from a simple COUNTA of the Login column? So eg 40 logins minus 10 zeroes equals 30 non-zeroes?